# Twitter Bootstrap Select Arrow Missing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm having an issue with the select drop down button in twitter bootstrap. It's happening in the two browsers I have installed on the machine (IE11, Chrome) and it's not just restricted to 'my sites'.

Here is a screenshot of the bootstrap website (OS: Windows 8.1 Broswer: Chrome) (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls):

[image: Example]

I have checked the console window and all resources are loading correctly.

Could anyone help me with why this is happening / steps to resolve?

Comment: You can also set glyphicon for that drop down

Comment: @BhaumikShah Not sure what you mean sorry?

Comment: Hi, You can follow this demo link :http://www.codeply.com/go/eQvhveHIU2

Comment: So just to make sure - before posting snippets, this is not an issue with code per se, but rather on your browsers. On ALL sites?

Comment: Please tell us exactly what your issue is. Is it that the icon is displaying, or that the icon is incorrect?

Comment: @Ibanez That's correct. It displays incorrectly across all browsers. Given that the code works on a different computer it all browsers, I can only assume it's a resource issue but nothing is loading incorrectly.

Comment: @JoshuaDwire The icon that is displayed is not correct. I'll update the question with a screenshot of the correct arrow when I'm not on my works network.

Comment: The arrow is chosen by the user's browser and can't be changed using CSS. If you must change it, you'll need to use a library that implements a select-like control using JS and HTML. See my answer.

Comment: In simple words, can you please - show us, what you are getting and what you want to achieve ! - other than `Select` styling, rest is confusion!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*TL;DR: you can't use CSS to change the icon. You'll have to use a library that implements a select-like control using HTML and JavaScript (at the expense of mobile-friendly selects on iOS and Android).*

The icon displayed in `<select>` is determined by the user's browser or operating system. You can't change it using CSS.

#### Select display in Chrome on a Mac:

[image: Select display in Chrome on a Mac]

#### Select display in Chrome on a Mac with some styles removed:

*I removed line-height, background-color, border, border-radius, and box-shadow. Note that the arrow has changed even though I didn't change any related style.*

[image: Select display in Chrome on a Mac with some styles removed]

#### Select display in Chrome on Windows:

[image: Select display in Chrome on Windows]

Notice that the icons are different, even though the code is the same.

### Now what?

Although select isn'g very styleable, there are many libraries that provide a very customizable implementation of a select-like control. I like to use [Bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/).

This library creates a `<div class="caret"></div>` that can be styled to change the icon. For example after including the Bootstrap-select JavaScript, the following code:

#### HTML

```html
<select class="selectpicker">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

#### CSS

```css
.caret{
    color: red;
}
```

#### Gives me this display:

[image: Bootstrap-select example image]

#### You'll lose mobile display, though:

*Using a custom library will disable the mobile-friendly way iOS and Android implement selects, so make sure a custom icon is important enough to you before proceeding.*

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joshua for your comprehensive answer (sorry for the late response wanted to wait till I had the time to properly digest!). I understand what you mean about a users browser and OS determining the display of the select arrow. It's also the source of my confusion though as the screenshot in the question is on a machine running Chrome in Windows and therefore would expect it to replicate you're screenshot and what I'd see on any other machine running chrome with Windows?

Comment: @Gareth Different versions of Windows can style the select differently.

Comment: @Gareth Also note that changing certain CSS styles, like `box-shadow` I think, will cause the browser to use a different icon.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to replicate the issue in exactly the same operating system and chrome version on a different machine and can't recreate the issue though which is why it's odd to me?

Comment: @Gareth It's possible one browser or OS has different settings or some accessibility mode enabled.

Comment: @JoshuaDwire can you tell about that select box dropdown arrow issue.How can we modify that ?

Comment: @Amit I'm not sure what your asking, but you'd probably need to use a third-party library like I suggested.

Comment: @JoshuaDwire i am sorry i forgot to mention that in firefox how can we modify the select box dropdown arrow ?

Comment: @Amit CSS doesn't let you change the arrow on a select. You'd need to use a third-party library to re-implement a select-like control.

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution to this, add this CSS and put 'form-override' class on each select dropdown:

```
.form-override {
  appearance: auto !important;
}
```

I'm not sure why this works or why it's needed, just wanted to share how I was able to fix this problem.  For me it seems to be sporadic, sometimes the problem occurs and I need this style setting to fix it, and sometimes it does not need this fix.

Comment: on my case, the arrow is missing on all of my select tag and this hack solved my problem `[+1]`

Answer (score 5):

Use [image: dropdown Image] for select

```
select {
-moz-appearance: none;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../images/dropdown.png") no-repeat scroll 100% center / 20px 13px !important;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 6px 20px 6px 6px !important;
width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't style the `<select>` element itself at this moment. Every browser applies its own styling to most form elements.

So you can create your own custom select by hiding the original one, create markup, e.g. `div` with `ul` + `li` and live it up with javascript.

**OR**

If you don't mind using jQuery, try these libraries:

- [SelectBoxIt](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/index.html)
- [Select2](https://select2.github.io/)
- [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)
- [Bootstrap select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)
- [jquery-selectBox](http://marcj.github.io/jquery-selectBox/)
- [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/)

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced that behavior with IE on Windows 8.1. For some reason IE renders the arrow differently as soon as you start to style the `select` element (which bootstrap themes usually do). Even something as simple as setting the background color triggers this behavior.

The only solution I've found so far is to style the arrow as needed. You can use the [::-ms-expand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465742.aspx) pseudo element for that. The following css rule should restore the "default" look:

```
select::-ms-expand {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
}
```