# add caret to select dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHAoo.png)   I want to add a bootstrap **caret** class in my select dropdown menu.

```css
.select_menu{
  font-size: 12px;
  outline: none;
  border: thin #ddd solid;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control select_menu" style="">
    <option>Click here to select purpose</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Options 2 </option>
</select>
```

I have used bootstrap form-control. How can I add caret to select dropdown menu.

Comment: check this link: https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Comment: You wan't it to be a dropdown menu where you click and go to a page - or do you wan't it to be a select where you choose something?

Comment: yes.. i want to be a select where i choose options in that.

Comment: i have edited question by putting image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32357172/6853759) - I think it will be right about what you're looking for.

The caret displayed in a `<select>` element is determined by the user's browser or OS. You *can* override this to set a custom caret/image; however, as described in the linked post, you risk diminishing the quality of experience on mobile devices.

Proceed with caution, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

bydefault caret is added in select box with bootstrap please follow the mentioned and you can see also on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/k0Lm7eL1/12/

```css
.select_menu{
  font-size: 12px;
  outline: none;
  border: thin #ddd solid;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group">

<select class="select_menu form-control" >
    <option>Click here to select purpose</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Options 2 </option>
</select>

</div>
```

Comment: i want only caret. dont want anything blow it. which is by default in bootstrap.

Comment: when i write `appearance: none;` then arrow gets disappear.