# Using Select Library with bootstrap - CSS looks odd?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

I've inherited a php/laravel project that appears to make use of bootstrap and select2.  Everytime I place a select element and call `.select2()` on it the design looks odd, it ends up looking like this:

Without clicked:

[image]

Clicked:

[image]

I don't see the arrow or the hover effect.  The former programmers did include the css files within select2 and combined them into one fairly large style sheet by using gulp.  I can inspect the element and it shows the correct classes being assigned. Not exactly sure what is wrong, I even tried to removed all bootstrap classes and it still looked like the images.

Here is the html:

```
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="plants">Plant</label>
                <select name="plants" id="plants" class="form-control">
                    @foreach ($plants as $plant)
                    <option value="{{$plant->code}}">{{$plant->code}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and for JQuery all I have for this element is

```
$("#plants").select2();
```

Can someone please help me with this?

### Edit

What I mean by odd is it does not look like the standard select2 drop downs from the select2 library page.  For instance, I am missing the arrow on the right of the drop down to show the user that they can click on the element and see options.  I am missing the highlight when I hover over a value, etc.  As an example, here is a fiddle that someone created showing these items that I am missing: http://jsfiddle.net/mmoore99/fqUhJ/3/

Comment: How do we solve "looks odd"? What is odd to you might me normal for me.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith - See my edit where I explain further please.  Thank You!

Comment: Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31102515/twitter-bootstrap-select-arrow-missing